# How to export class to dll without Decorated/Mangled names?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

I am trying to export a class called `Point`:

```
class _declspec(dllexport) Point
{
public:
    void output(int x, int y);
};
```

when I use `dumpbin.exe` tool to look at the dll,it shows me:

> ??4Point@@QAEAAV0@$$QAV0@@Z = @ILT+760(??4Point@@QAEAAV0@$$QAV0@@Z)
>   ??4Point@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z = @ILT+240(??4Point@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z)
>   ?output@Point@@QAEXHH@Z = @ILT+450(?output@Point@@QAEXHH@Z)

I know use `extern "C"` or a `def` file to avoid names mangled when I exports functions,but how can I do when I exports a class?

Comment: That is not possible.  Nor necessary.

Comment: Why do you need this?